# What does "row +: savedState.toSeq" do in StateStoreRestoreExec.doExecute?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

we can see StateStoreRestoreExec as follows.

```
case class StateStoreRestoreExec(
    keyExpressions: Seq[Attribute],
    stateId: Option[OperatorStateId],
    child: SparkPlan)
  extends UnaryExecNode with StateStoreReader {

  override protected def doExecute(): RDD[InternalRow] = {
    val numOutputRows = longMetric("numOutputRows")

  child.execute().mapPartitionsWithStateStore(
    getStateId.checkpointLocation,
    operatorId = getStateId.operatorId,
    storeVersion = getStateId.batchId,
    keyExpressions.toStructType,
    child.output.toStructType,
    sqlContext.sessionState,
    Some(sqlContext.streams.stateStoreCoordinator)) { case (store, iter) =>
      val getKey = GenerateUnsafeProjection.generate(keyExpressions, child.output)
      iter.flatMap { row =>
        val key = getKey(row)
        val savedState = store.get(key)
        numOutputRows += 1
        row +: savedState.toSeq
      }
}
```

Here, I wonder the meaning of `row +: savedState.toSeq` . I think row is a instance of UnsafeRow and savedState.toSeq is a instance of Seq. So how can we operate them with `+:`. On the other hand, I think savedState is a instance of UnsafeRow and toSeq is not a member of UnsaveRow, So how does `savedState.toSeq` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row` is an instance of an `InternalRow`, and `savedState` is an `Option[UnsafeRow]`, which extends `InternalRow`. What happens here is that the saved state is transformed from `Option[UnsafeRow]` to a `Seq[UnsafeRow]` and then the `row` instance is prepended to that sequence.

When you `flatMap` over these `UnsafeRow` objects, you get back an `Iterator[UnsafeRow]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am clear now. In addition, what is the meaning of key? And you say "map over each of these UnsafeRow", I think you mean "flapmap over each of these UnsafeRow"

Comment: @GOGO `StateStore` holds state in memory in key value pairs, so that when needed it can do a fast lookup for the value by key, the same way a `HashMap` works (it is actually backed by a concurrent hash map internally to store the key value pairs).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can see it is actually backed by a concurrent hash map but I wonder what the key is. For example, I can use a ID which is Int type as a key and use a NAME which is String type as a value to record a mapping ID->NAME. But I am confused about how `StateStore` organize the data.

Comment: _"StateStore holds state in memory in key value pairs"_ « I think it's not correct as by default it's HDFS-compatible file system using `HDFSBackedStateStore`.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski The state store is only used for writing snapshots and deltas of files to a persistent storage for fault tolerance. The data is still backed in memory by a `ConcurrentHashMap` for fast lookup. When you think about it, this makes sense because when a new `StreamingQuery` has to execute with a feature such as deduplicate, it has to do a fast lookup of all keys in memory and remove duplicates.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Right. I've just reviewed (and described) that part of Structured Streaming so thanks a lot for confirming my thoughts. Answer upvoted!

Comment: I am still confused about the key. key is obtained by `getKey(row)`. Here what the key is. Could you please give me a case ?@YuvalItzchakov  I think rows from different batchs are different. Here it use `getKey(row)` to get key and the use key to get old data from store but I think it can not get old data because the row is new and the key dose not exist.